# Display selected X labels on line chart in achartengine

Tags: achartengine

I am plotting huge amount of data on line chart in achartengine. There are around 500 points to be plotted.
But i see that x labels over lap so much that it looks like one thick line/bar!
I am plotting time with 2 minute intervals on x axis.
What i want is instead of displaying time at 2 minute interval i want to display the same on hourly basis which will bring down the x axis labels to around 12-15.

How can i do that?Please help.

this is my code.

```
XYSeries minSeries = new XYSeries("Min");
        XYSeries maxSeries = new XYSeries("Max");
        XYSeries actualSeries = new XYSeries("Actual");

        ArrayList<Double> minDataList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> maxDataList = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> actualDataList = new ArrayList<Double>();

        if(jsonData.containsKey("Min")) {
            Utility.tokenizeData(jsonData.get("Min"), minDataList);
            for (int i =0;i<minDataList.size();i++) {
                System.out.println("MIn value in line chart is "+minDataList.get(i));
                minSeries.add(i,minDataList.get(i));
            }
        }
        if(jsonData.containsKey("Max")) {
            Utility.tokenizeData(jsonData.get("Max"), maxDataList);
            for (int i = 0;i<maxDataList.size();i++) {
                maxSeries.add(i,maxDataList.get(i));
            }
        }
        int minLen = minDataList.size();
        Double minVal = minDataList.get(0);
        Double maxValue = maxDataList.get(0);
        int actLength = actualDataList.size()-minDataList.size();
        for(int a=minLen;a<actLength;a++){
            minSeries.add(a,minVal);
            maxSeries.add(a,maxValue);
        }
        if(jsonData.containsKey("Actual")) {
            Utility.tokenizeData(jsonData.get("Actual"), actualDataList);
            for (int i = 0;i<actualDataList.size();i++) {
                actualSeries.add(i,actualDataList.get(i));
            }
        }
        dataset.addSeries(minSeries);
        dataset.addSeries(maxSeries);
        dataset.addSeries(actualSeries);

        // Now we create the renderer
        XYSeriesRenderer minrenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        minrenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        minrenderer.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        // Include low and max value
        minrenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        // we add point markers
        minrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        minrenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);
        minrenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        minrenderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // Now we create the renderer
        XYSeriesRenderer maxrenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        maxrenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        maxrenderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        // Include low and max value
        maxrenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        // we add point markers
        //hvacrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        maxrenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);
        maxrenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        maxrenderer.setFillPoints(true);

        // Now we create the renderer
        XYSeriesRenderer actrenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        actrenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        actrenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        // Include low and max value
        actrenderer.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        // we add point markers
        //lgtrenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        actrenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(3);
        actrenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        actrenderer.setFillPoints(true);

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(minrenderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(maxrenderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(actrenderer);

        mRenderer.setYAxisMin(-10);

if(jsonData.containsKey(Constant.TAG_CATEGORIES) && jsonData.get(Constant.TAG_CATEGORIES) != null)  {
        Utility.tokenizeStringData(jsonData.get(Constant.TAG_CATEGORIES), categoryList);
    }
    for(int l=0;l<categoryList.size();l++){
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(l, (String)categoryList.get(l));

    }
    mRenderer.setXLabels(20);
    mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
    // We want to avoid black border
    mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
    // transparent margins // Disable Pan on two axis
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
   // mRenderer.setYAxisMax(3);
    //mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    //mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);

    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(25.0f);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(30.5f);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30.0f);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Temperature");
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(30.0f);
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Celsius(C)");
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 30, 50, 0});
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.DKGRAY);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

I want to plot all points but display only subset of xaxis labels so that it looks clean!

Answer (score 0):

Got solution to this problem and it was very simple!

Just increment the loop counter to what ever number you like while setting the xaxis labels.

```
for(int l=0;l<categoryList.size();){
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(l, (String)categoryList.get(l));
        l=l+30;
    }
```